# Extended option in TinyMCE doesn't work

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla3.0

I've used TinyMCe but suddenly its extended option doesn't work. When I change it to simple option or advanced option it works perfect. What it the problem and how can I fix it? I use Joomla 3.4 and don't update these days.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is probably not the answer you are looking for but updating Joomla and third party extensions to the latest version might help.

Joomla 3.4 is missing high severity security updates and the site could have been compromised.